# Solve the equation $\frac{x+1}{x-1}+\frac{x-2}{x+2}+\frac{x-3}{x+3}+\frac{x+4}{x-4}=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}+\dfrac{x-2}{x+2}+\dfrac{x-3}{x+3}+\dfrac{x+4}{x-4}=4.$$
First we have $x\ne 1;-2;-3;4$. Now we can multiply the whole equation by $$(x-1)(x+2)(x+3)(x-4)$$ but this doesn't seem very clever because the calculations won't be easy. Is there something else we can do?

> $$\dfrac12\left(-1\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{69}{5}}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{x+a}{x-a}-1=\dfrac{x+a-(x-a)}{x-a}$$

So, we  have $$\dfrac2{x-1}+\dfrac8{x-4}=\dfrac4{x+2}+\dfrac6{x+3}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! So now I can multiply by the common nonzero denominator?

Comment: @Medi, Yes, there will be some cancellations

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong but it doesn't look very straight-forward. The last equation you wrote is equivalent to $$\dfrac{2(x-4)+8(x-1)}{(x-1)(x-4)}=\dfrac{4(x+3)+6(x+2)}{(x+2)(x+3)}\\ \dfrac{10x-16}{(x-1)(x-4)}=\dfrac{10x+24}{(x+2)(x+3)}\\ (x-1)(x-4)(10x+24)=(10x-16)(x+2)(x+3)\\2(x-1)(x-4)(5x+12)=2(5x-8)(x+2)(x+3)\\ (x^2-5x+4)(5x+12)=(5x-8)(x^2+5x+6)$$ Should I continue the computation or I can calculate it easier?

Comment: @Medi, Cancel $x^3$ to find $$x^2(12-25)+x(-60+20)+48=x^2(-8+25)+x(30-40)-48$$

Comment: I didn't get where does this equation come from?

Comment: @Medi, Just expand both sides

Comment: Calculation's won't be easy? Not at all. Multiply with the common denominator and you obtain $5x^2+5x-16=0$. Then we obtain the two solutions.